# Flet-App: Hot reload feature does not work

Tags: python, flutter, flet

I'm working my way through the first flet python tutorial to create a todo app (https://flet.dev/docs/tutorials/).

I noticed that a lot of people are using a hot reload, so they can edit the code an immediatly see the result. I have to call `python todo.py` and then see my result, for every change I have to restart this. I installed flet with the following command: `python -m pip install flet`.

I've seen on youtube sombody call `flet todo.py` for the hot reload, but this does not work for me. Can you tell me what I need to install to get the hot reload feature?

Answer (score 0):

flet run main.py --android

hot reload

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).